# get phone accent brush programmatically c#

Tags: windows-phone

I have textbox in xaml

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiLight}" Margin="12,10,12,0" />
```

How can I get value of phoneaccentbrush,  programmatically (c#) from system resource of windows phone 7 / 7.5 / 8 so that i can set the foreground-color to match the accent selected in the WP's settings.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

First, you need to create currentAccentColorHex before Constructor of you C# class:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    Color currentAccentColorHex = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentColor"];

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {          
        //...
```

and then use it wherever you need to set color for the control: Example for Background property for control MyControl:

```
SolidColorBrush backColor = new SolidColorBrush(currentAccentColorHex);
MyControl.Background = backColor;
```

Hope this help

Comment: Unfortunately the app has to be restarted after a theme change with this method. Otherwise the old theme values will be pulled out of the Ressource dictionary.

Answer (score 10):

thanks Spaso :) I did little more research and with your help I came up with following code

```
var phoneAccentBrush =  new SolidColorBrush((App.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"] as SolidColorBrush).Color);
```

Comment: Interesting. I deliberately avoid not to send you a code like yours, just to be more clear what is going on. Ok, both code works.

Comment: Spaso, gave you an upvote for providing the solution in the first place

Comment: I got error "Cannot find a resource with the given key" with the above line of code. I'm also attempting this in a Shared Code project, so I can share the code between Phone & Tablet apps. Not sure if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your textbox at xaml

```
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}"
```

or set this from c#

```
btnDefault.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush((Color)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentColor"]);
```