# Accessability Font and Colors Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am wanting to change the font color of an unread textblock to the phones default accent colour much the same way outlook email client does on windows phone. I needed to create a brush as showin in the answer provided so not a duplicate thanks

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="292" Height="130">
        <Border Height="100" Width="100" Margin="10,10,0,10">
            <Image Source="/Assets/termin.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        </Border>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding description}" 
                       Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="200" Height="30" 
                       TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" 
                       Margin="10,2,0,0" Width="200" Height="30" 
                       TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                       FontSize="{ThemeResource ContentControlFontSize}" Opacity="0.49"/>


                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>

        </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

What I was thinking of doing was when I am creating my list from my parse.com object was to filter the unread property as follows

```
if (parseObject.ContainsKey("unread"))
 {
    Boolean isUnread = (bool) parseObject["unread"];
    if (isUnread == true)
     {
       mlist.MessageColour = What do i place here for fone accent colur
       mlist.Unread = isUnread;
     }
}
```

My question is what should i store to get the correct accent color here in code behind I see how to do it with xaml and theme resource but bare in mind id be binding this to the syle property of a textblock i persume.

Also does anybody no how to retrieve the font size  that is set in the setings accessabilty or do i just not set a fontsize for my app to get the default.

Comment: possible duplicate of [get phone accent brush programmatically c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14039981/get-phone-accent-brush-programmatically-c-sharp)

Comment: not really as I wanting to store the color value just here in the list item

Comment: actually yes please mark and duplicate the above worked

Comment: @PawełMach its actually the brush color i need as setting the foreground

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of color-related things in Windows Phone, and to some extent also WPF or anything written in XAML, are of abstract type `Brush`. You need to create a brush - in case of single color `SolidColorBrush` - and set it as Foreground of TextBlock. If you want to bind it to View, you are going to need a property of type Brush.

Snippet below should do the trick.

```
var color = (Color)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentColor"];
mlist.MessageColour = new SolidColorBrush(color);
```

Comment: Mach thanks that worked is it comment practice to use accent color for unread messages or is their an accent color for the unread state also about fontsize how do i get the default method.

Comment: how woud reference this then in xaml would i just do my usual {Binding MessageColour} or would i need to do someting else to create the brush first.

Comment: You do not need to create brushes, if `mlist.MessageColour` is of type `Brush`. And AFAIK, even if it is not, but can be cast to `Brush`, it should be fine. Default size of font is set by default in any `TextBlock`, just do not write anything. If you want, you will need to access it similarly as the color, just change string in square brackets.

Comment: So do i just add {Biding ImagePath}

Comment: I'd say you probably meant `{Binding MessageColour}`, if `mlist` is your DataContext. If not, it will be `{Binding mlist.MessageColour}`.